# PostgreSQL hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to use Hibernate with Spring and PostgreSQL, but I have lots of errors like:

```
org.postgresql.Driver   : Connection error 
ERROR 3424 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

I have put postgreSQL.Driver in my libs but nothing to do error say there.

Edit:

```
2018-03-19 15:54:53.660  INFO 7640 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-03-19 15:54:54.664  WARN 7640 --- [           main] unknown.jul.logger                       : ConnectException occurred while connecting to localhost:5432`
`at com.ttmik.back.MainKt.main(main.kt:19) ~[classes/:na]
2018-03-19 15:54:54.675 ERROR 7640 --- [           main] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Comment: Please add full stack trace of the exception as well as your HikariCP configuration.

Comment: I have added my errors

Comment: You shouldn't have truncated the log before the line where it logs the actual Postgres error message

Comment: I think there is an error with the port number...

Comment: PostgreSQL is either not listening on localhost, or at least not on port 5432, or it is blocked by your firewall.

Comment: I have change with this line :

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PostgreSQL can be reached by using telnet. If you get something like:

```
telnet localhost 5432
Connecting To localhost... 
Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connection failed
```

then most likely need to change `listen_addresses` to `*` in `postgresql.conf` file as per [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/380398/setting-up-postgres-cant-connect-remotely-to-postgres-server#380404).